# How do I get the selected and deselected items in a QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt4, selection, qtreewidget

I have a tree-widget to which I am adding items. Now I need to call a custom procedure when the item is selected or the item previously selected is unselected (Note: I am learning both Python and Qt - the later seem to by a little too much for me).

```
for i in vector:
     parent = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget)
     parent.setText(0, i[0])
     parent.setText(1, i[1])
     parent.setText(2,i[2])
     parent.setCheckState(0,QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [selectionChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) signal of the tree-widget's selection-model:

```
        selmodel = self.treeWidget.selectionModel()
        selmodel.selectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelection)
        ...

    def handleSelection(self, selected, deselected):
        for index in selected.indexes():
            item = self.treeWidget.itemFromIndex(index)
            print('SEL: row: %s, col: %s, text: %s' % (
                index.row(), index.column(), item.text(0)))
        for index in deselected.indexes():
            item = self.treeWidget.itemFromIndex(index)
            print('DESEL: row: %s, col: %s, text: %s' % (
                index.row(), index.column(), item.text(0)))
```